# Crear disparadores .click dentro de un bucle for

Tags: jquery, eventos, trigger, bucle-for

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  console.log($("body").find("form label input")); //da un objeto, una lista, con los diferentes inputs dentro del label dentro del form

  for (var i = 0; i < $("body").find("form label input").length; i++) {

    console.log($("body").find("form label input")[i]); //repite cada uno de los objetos seleccionados por orden
    $("body").find("form label input")[i].click(function(){ //parece ignorar la creación del disparador o eventListener.
      alert("¿hola?"); //no se ejecuta el alert
    });

  }

}
```

¿Porque no se crea un eventListener para cada input en cada repetición del blucle? No lo entiendo...

Comment: ¿Tendrás un ejemplo funcional con código HTML para hacer pruebas? Para así saber si hay que cambiar tu selector o tu ciclo

Comment: ya que estas usando jquery... no seria mas sencillo darle una clase a tus objetos y agregar los disparadoes a todos con un solo `$(".clase").click(...);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con jQuery es muy fácil, solo tienes que identificar a cuales elementos les quieres dar click y asignarlos en los selectores de jQuery que son los mismos de CSS.

Así evitas recorrer ciclos en los objetos del DOM porque al recorrerlos también te recorre las funciones y otros métodos que el tiene, ósea consumirías menos recursos del PC.

```js
        $(function(){
            //Agrega el evento click a todos los elementos que tengan la clase "item"
            $(".item").on("click", function( a ){
                alert( "Hola: "+$(a.currentTarget).html())
            })
        })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="item"> Click me 1 </li>
<li class="item"> Click me 2 </li>
<li class="item"> Click me 3 </li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Puede crear un `Listener` directamente desde `JavaScript`. mediante [addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) de la siguiente Forma:

```
var inputs = $("body").find("form label input");
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
        alert(this.name);
    });
}
```

Aunque desde Jquery hubiese bastado con

```
$(document).on('click', 'form label input', function(event) {
    /* Acciones a Realizar después del Evento Click */
});
```